# listview in dialougbox shows nothing

Tags: java, android, listview, android-dialog

i have this code to show `listview` in `dialogbox` frame of `listview` is shown but without any text in it(i have background colored `listview`)

```
 public void shw(View view)
    {

        Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Dialog Title");
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custadd);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custadd,null);
        ListView lv=(ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listv);
        String s1[]={"sunday","monday","tuesday"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                R.layout.simple_list_item, s1 );
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        dialog.show();

    }
```

Comment: `R.layout.custadd` two times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public void shw(View view) {

    Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setTitle("Dialog Title");     
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custadd);    
    ListView lv=(ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listv);    
    String s1[]={"sunday","monday","tuesday"};

     ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, s1 );
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    dialog.show();

}
```

Comment: still no text in listview buddy

Comment: @rockhack check updated ans its working i have tested in my device

Comment: so i have the dialog which open in a fragment class called cart and this code is in main activity where this fragment is loaded

Comment: didn't  get you @rockhack

Comment: @rockhack happy to help you enjoy codding

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the view you display `ListView` is not the view you set for your `Dialog`. You should fix as below:

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
dialog.setTitle("Dialog Title");
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custadd,null    );
dialog.setContentView(convertView); // set convertView as content view. 
// you can find listview and then fill data here
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custadd);` and set view for dialog when it get's inflated `dialog.setContentView(convertView);` and the issue will be resolved.